# auto_ptr for arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

In short, I am wondering if there is an auto_ptr like type for arrays.  I know I could roll my own, I'm just making sure that there isn't already something out there.

I know about vectors as well. however I don't think I can use them.  I am using several of the Windows APIs/SDKs such as the Windows Media SDK, Direct Show API which in order to get back some structures to call a function which takes a pointer and a size twice.  The first time passing NULL as the pointer to get back the size of the structure that I have to allocated in order to receive the data I am looking for.  For example:

```
CComQIPtr<IWMMediaProps> pProps(m_pStreamConfig);
DWORD cbType = 0;
WM_MEDIA_TYPE *pType = NULL;

hr = pProps->GetMediaType(NULL, &cbType);
CHECK_HR(hr);

pType = (WM_MEDIA_TYPE*)new BYTE[cbType];   // Would like to use auto_ptr instread
hr = pProps->GetMediaType(pType, &cbType);
CHECK_HR(hr);

// ... do some stuff

delete[] pType;
```

Since cbType typically comes back bigger than sizeof(WM_MEDIA_TYPE) due to the fact is has a pointer to another structure in it, I can't just allocate WM_MEDIA_TYPE objects.  Is there anything like this out there?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use

```
std::vector<BYTE> buffer(cbType);
pType = (WM_MEDIA_TYPE*)&buffer[0];
```

or since **C++11**

```
std::vector<BYTE> buffer(cbType);
pType = (WM_MEDIA_TYPE*)buffer.data();
```

instead.

---

Additional:
If someone is asking if the [Vectors are guaranteed to be contiguous](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/) the answer is **Yes** since C++ 03 standard. There is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168/are-stdvector-elements-guaranteed-to-be-continguous) that already discussed it.

---

If **C++11** is supported by your compiler, unique_ptr can be used for arrays.

```
unique_ptr<BYTE[]> buffer(new BYTE[cbType]);
pType = (WM_MEDIA_TYPE*)buffer.get();
```

Comment: Are vectors guaranteed to be contiguous blocks of memory?

Comment: @Heavyd Yes - the c++ standard guarantees this.

Comment: I'm all for using std::vector, but if the array isn't intended to be resizable (and in this case, isn't really an array at all) std::vector might be a little overkill.

Comment: @Evan - why? At runtime it boils down to just a pointer to a hunk of memory.

Comment: @Evan I disagree. If you don't use a std::vector you are going to have to use a smart pointer or write all the delete code yourself, fielding exception problems etc. In either case, std::vector is no more complex, and may well be simpler.

Comment: Because std::vector is a template the compiler will either way only create the code that is really needed. So at the end it will end up in the same code that you need for your new/delete pair.

Comment: @Earwicker a pointer, memory, plus current size and potential size.

Comment: I went with the unique_ptr solution since vector was overkill for my arrays (They never need to be resized or anything like that)

Comment: Can you fix the example of using std::vector<>::data(). data() already returns a pointer, so no need for '&'.

Comment: Would there be a reason to use `buffer.data();` over `&buffer[0];` or is it just being mentioned because it is a possible variation after C++11?

Comment: `buffer.data();`is defined to not throw if container is empty. It will return nullptr instead. `&buffer[0]`might or will throw. So using `data()` avoid the need of extra code for zero size containers.

Answer (score 10):

boost [`scoped_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) or you can use boost [`scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) with a custom deleter

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing for this in the current std library. However, the future standard C++0x has an unique_ptr, which comes in replacement of auto_ptr, and which works with arrays.

A first implementation can be found here:
[unique_ptr](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/unique_ptr03.html)

Comment: you should make it clear that for unique_ptr to work, you'll need to supply a custom deleter.

Comment: Not necessarily, see section "Safe Support For Arrays"

Answer (score 3):

Not in STL.  Boost has some smart pointers with a similar idea.  Check out [scoped_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) and [shared_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm)