# Why operator [] is not allowed on std::auto_ptr

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010, auto-ptr

Why operator [] is not allowed on std::auto_ptr?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

template <typename T>
void foo( T capacity )
{
    auto_ptr<T> temp = new T[capacity];

    for( size_t i=0; i<capacity; ++i )
        temp[i] = i; // Error
}

int main()
{
    foo<int>(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled on Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.

**Error:** error C2676: binary '[' : 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ auto_ptr for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044785/c-auto-ptr-for-arrays)

Comment: The parameter type for `capacity` should probably be something other than `T`, by the way.

Comment: Can you elaborate why `std::vector<T>` would not meet your needs?

Comment: @fbrereto - Just learning `std::auto_ptr`. And got struck and surprised by this error. It's just a learning part.

Comment: Note that in C++0x, `std::unique_ptr` (`std::auto_ptr`'s superior replacement), is specialized for array types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is that `auto_ptr` will free the content using `delete` instead of `delete[]`, and so `auto_ptr` is not suitable for handling heap-allocated arrays (constructed with `new[]`) and is only suitable for handling single, heap-allocated arrays that were constructed with `new`.

Supporting `operator[]` would encourage developers to use it for arrays and would mistakenly give the impression that the type can support arrays when, in fact, it cannot.

If you want a smartpointer-like array class, use [boost::scoped_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm).

Comment: @Michael - Other than using `boost` library, is there any other smart pointer that can do this job, available in standard headers.

Comment: @Mahesh: yes -- it's called `std::vector`. Despite the name, it's fundamentally a smart pointer for an array of objects.

Comment: @Jerry: heh, and unlike any of the other smart pointers it has clone semantics on assignment. Genius!

Comment: @Jerry Coffin - Got you. Thanks. ( This is for your previous comment on std::vector )

Comment: @Jerry: sadly it falls short of combining clone semantics with runtime polymorphism, though. A proper clone pointer is quite hard.

Comment: @Steve: quite true -- even so, I find vector much more useful that most of what people usually think of as smart pointers.

Comment: @Jerry: Me too. But then I don't very often share object-ownership, and I return by value until proven otherwise, so much of the time dynamic polymorphism is the only thing smart pointers are *for*. I don't think I've ever used `scoped_array` in anger.

Answer (score 2):

Because `std::auto_ptr` is not intended to be used with arrays.

Besides, In your sample

```
std::auto_ptr<T> temp = new T(capacity); // T=int, capacity=5
```

actually allocates a *single* `int` and initializes it with `capacity`. It does not create an array of integers as you seem to have intended.

Comment: I intended to use `[]`. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: @Mahesh: Still an error.  `auto_ptr` is not compatible with arrays.  Initializing an `auto_ptr` with `new[]` causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Ben Voigt- You should have posted it as an answer instead. Another learnt point for today. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `auto_ptr` is designed to hold a pointer to a single element; it will use `delete` (specifically not `delete[]`) on its destruction.

Your example is not doing what (I think) you think it does. Or at least the name capacity is misleading, because you are only allocating a single element (and assigning the value of  capacity` to it). Your for loop has no sensible meaning.

Answer (score 1):

`auto_ptr` and other smart pointers are only intended to store a pointer to a single object. This is because they use `delete` in the destructor, rather than `delete[]`, which would be needed if it were storing a pointer to an array.

If you need to wrap an array of objects in a smart pointer, the standard library doesn't offer anything to help. However, Boost does offer `scoped_array`, which behaves similar to `std::auto_ptr` and is made to hold arrays of objects created by `new[]`.