# Smart pointer to wrap array returned by a library

Tags: c++, boost, stl, smart-pointers, visual-c++-2005

I'm running VC++ 2005 so `std::unique_ptr` is not available AFAIK. I use some library functions (black box) which effectively do `return new T[n]` and I want to wrap the result in some object which will mean I don't have to delete them in my destructor.

Does anything exist in the standard libraries circa VC++ 2008? If not, would the boost version of unique_ptr work perfectly as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713484/smart-pointers-and-arrays)?

To clarify some confusion in the comments, the library function returns a raw pointer to a dynamically allocated array and I don't have access to change that... I need to take that pointer and wrap it in an object which automatically calls `delete []` when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: Does it have a ctor which takes in a pointer to pre-allocated memory? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/ If you can provide a working example the answer is yours :)

Comment: you can give it an initial size and it is a contiguous block of memory. What is the type of `T` ?

Comment: @hmjd: it does not work with pre-allocated memory though, so not really an option unless you can modify the library itself.

Comment: In VC++ 2008 (I think SP1 is needed) you have [TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1), so you have shared_ptr, but not unique_ptr. It can do the trick, but it can also be dangerous, if the pointers are not meant to be shared.

Comment: @John, I also misread the question. I thought you had control of the library functions.

Comment: Why dont you roll your own unique_ptr like class, it shouldnt be difficult, something like: template<typename T> struct CSmartArrayDeleter { T* t; ~CSmartArrayDeleter(){ delete[] t; } void Set(T* p) { t = p; }}; With some additional null pointer checking.

Comment: @luskan - because the whole point of STL/boost is we don't keep making our own versions of everything.

Comment: @luskan: Because it's easy to forget important details, like inhibiting the default copy constructor and copy-assignment operator, and remembering to delete the previous object on assignment.

Comment: I agree, I am also stuck in VS2005 world, and I am not even allowed to use boost or any external libs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044785/c-auto-ptr-for-arrays - show a solution with vector, but to me it looks more scary than rolling your own solution

Comment: @luskan I'm still awaiting a response if boost is allowed :)

Answer (score 0):

In the pre-2011 standard library, all you've got is `auto_ptr`, which is suitable for returning from functions. However, it only works with single objects, not arrays, so it's not suitable for this use.

As far as I can tell, there isn't a `unique_ptr` in Boost. There is a `scoped_ptr` and `scoped_array`, but they aren't transferable and so can't be returned from a function.

`boost::shared_array` might be suitable, although it uses reference counting and so has a (hopefully small) overhead compared to a single-ownership pointer.

`std::vector` might be a good choice; as long as your compiler supports "return value optimisation" then you can (with a little bit of care) return one from a function without any unnecessary memory allocation or copying. However, it has the disadvantage that it doesn't prevent accidental copying of the data.

UPDATE: I've just noticed the words "black box" in your question, which I think might imply that the library functions return raw pointers, and you want to assign them to a smart pointer that will destroy them with `delete []`, and can't modify the functions themselves. If that's the case, [`boost::scoped_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) should do the trick, and apologies to the people who deleted their answers in response to my comments.

Comment: `std::vector` is only suitable if you can change the library itself, I am not sure this is the OP's case here.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Yes, I just noticed that I misread the question. I thought he wanted to return a smart pointer, not deal with a returned raw pointer.

Comment: `boost::unique_ptr` appears to exist (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/unique_ptr.html) but whether it's the same as modern `std::unique_ptr` I don't know. However if we're using boost, it looks like `boost::scoped_array` is even nicer for a class member variable which wraps an array needing deletion on class destruction.

Comment: @John: `boost::interprocess::unique_ptr` is intended for sharing memory between processes (being in the `interprocess` namespace). I don't know whether it's suitable for managing normal memory, and it looks like you'd have to provide your own deleter to deal with arrays, unlike `std::unique_ptr` which is specialised for arrays. `scoped_array` sounds more suitable, especially if you don't need to transfer ownership.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do with the resulting value.

In general, I would advise `boost::scoped_ptr` and `boost::scoped_array` in C++03. However note that they were crafted with a very specific mindset: to limit the scope of the resource. That is, they go further than just handling cleanup, they also guarantee that the resource will not leave the scope, ie cannot be transferred to the caller.

If you want more, it's not easy in C++03 (because of the absence of movable types). In this case, you might need to craft an "extended" `boost::scoped_ptr`, adding a `release` method for example to allow passing memory to the caller (which is then expecting to be taking care of it properly).