# std vector + default allocator + direct array access?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

If I create a std::vector with the default allocator like this:

```
vector<int> myVec = vector<int>();
myVec.push_back(3);
myVec.push_back(5);
myVec.push_back(8);
```

Does the vector then store the actual data internally into an array of int?  Is it possible to get a pointer to this array and iterate directly over it using this pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, vector is designed so you can do this, use `&myVec[0]` to get an `int*`.  You can also use vector's iterator type, which behaves similarly.  (Pointers are valid random-access iterators.)  That you're using the default allocator, or any other allocator, doesn't change any of this, it's a required part of vector's interface.

Vectors are [guaranteed](http://www.google.com/search?q=is+vector+contiguous) to use contiguous storage.  In particular from those many results, check [this one](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/showpost.php?p=1484525&postcount=8) from Stroustrup himself.

Comment: The only caveat to this is that if you add or remove elements, you could cause a reallocation which could move the vector in memory.

Answer (score 0):

For `gcc 4.4` this operator is defined as:

```
operator[](size_type __n)
{ return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
```

So, we can say that items are stored as a regular array, and you can access them directly

**Edited**

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, but I did add the last paragraph in my answer in response---you can access it directly.

Comment: yeah, you can access it `_M_impl._M_start` should point to it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168/are-stdvector-elements-guaranteed-to-be-continguous here is another useful answer on the same question