# is std::vector same as array[number]?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are std::vector elements guaranteed to be contiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168/are-stdvector-elements-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous)

does std::vector always contain the data in sequential memory addresses as array[number]?

Comment: Duplicate of [Are std::vector elements guaranteed to be contiguous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168/are-stdvector-elements-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all types except bool, the standard requires the elements are contiguous in memory:

> 23.2.4/1 ... The elements of a vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is a vector where T is some type other than bool, then it obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size()

Do keep in mind that `std::vector<bool>` has special requirements and is not the same as an array of bool.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Given:

```
std::vector<int> arr;
```

you can be sure that

```
&arr[0]
```

will give you a pointer to a contiguous array of ints that can (for instance) be passed legacy APIs.

Comment: No, you can't. The standard allocator allocates memory with new. Allocated memory is *not* an array. The whole premise is wrong. I might be picky, but it's still true. Allocated memory is not an array. They simply share semantics.

Comment: Typically you write it as &arr.front()

Comment: @Brian R. Bondy: I would disagree. &arr[0] is what is specified in Effective STL, and I've never seen anyone use &arr.front() myself. &arr[0] is also the specification in the standard 23.2.4/1 quoted in R Samuel Klatchko's post.

Comment: @Billy: OK fair enough, I have just seen it the .front way everywhere before.

Comment: @Mads: What are you talking about? The standard is very clear about this issue: "Entities created by a *new-expression* have dynamic storage duration [...] If the entity is a nonarray object, the *new-expression* returns a pointer to the object created. If it is an array, the *new-expression* returns a pointer to the initial element **of the array**."

Comment: FredOverflow: A pointer is not an array. They share some semantics, but that's all. Because of the standard allocator, I would not call Vector for an array. Is that better? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It does not, however, allocate on the stack.

Comment: Unless of course you passed it an allocator that does just that.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: I don't see how creation of such an allocator is possible, given that such an allocator's data has to persist past the allocator's `allocate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the vector use sequential memory for all the elements stored. That means random access is almost as fast as normal array's index.

But vector allocate its memory in heap instead of stack. So it could be less less efficient in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the standard allocator, you can be sure that the allocated memory is continuous when using std::vector. In other words, foo[n+1] is the next element in the sequence after foo[n]. But std::vector is *not* an array, just like

```
int* blah = new int[100];
```

is not an array. But

```
int blah[100];
```

made on the stack is an array.
Pointers to allocated memory and arrays just happen to share semantics. They are not equal per the standard, so don't confuse the two.

Comment: This is not correct.  `new int[100]` does indeed create an array.  "Entities created by a new-expression have dynamic storage duration... If [the entity] is an array, the new-expression returns a pointer to the initial element of the array" (C++03 §5.3.4/1).  `blah` is not an array, but the object created by `new int[100]` is.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for the correction :-)