# using a char array to hold an array of arbitrarily sized objects, alignment issues?

Tags: c++, odbc

I want to pass in an array of parameters to SQLBindParameters, and have this array held in a char array(since I don't know the type beforehand) (I want all the elements in the 'array' to be the same).

I'll have a pointer to a sample parameter type, and the size of the parameter.

```
void *buffer = getBuffer();
int bufferLength = getBufferLength();
const int numElements = 200; //for example

char *array = new char[bufferLength * numElements];

for(int i=0; i < numElements; ++i)
{
    memcpy(array + (i * bufferLength), buffer, bufferLength)
}

// now use array in SQLBindParameter call
```

will this work as expected, without any alignment issues? (i.e., the same as if I had just declared an array of the right type to start with)

Comment: Are you asking the same thing as [Are std::vector elements guaranteed to be contiguous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168/are-stdvector-elements-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous)?

Comment: actually, I shouldn't even have mentioned the vector, my question is more if it would work, even if vectorBuffer was declared as char *VectorBuffer = new char[]

Comment: @Troubadour: No, he isn't. He is asking whether the memory used by a `std::vector` is suitably aligned for any data to put into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `vector` with an allocator that uses `operator new` under the hood, then the C++ standard guarantees that an array of `char` allocated with `new` will be aligned suitably for use with any data type.

EDIT: Yes, `new char[]` is guaranteed to be aligned for use with any type.

EDIT2: Do note that a local (stack) array `char foo[]` has no such alignment guarantees.

Comment: You mean, an array with automatic storage duration. (And/or static storage duration?) It may not be on the actual stack, and it may not be "local" (for some value of "local"). Be precise, please!

Comment: Not that it matters now the question has changed, but does the standard guarantee that `vector` locates the elements of the vector starting from the beginning of the array that it allocates? You'd hope so, since by design a vector is *supposed* to replace a dynamically-allocated array, so it would be a shame if it was missing a useful property of those. But I don't recall seeing such a guarantee. For other containers it *doesn't* necessarily locate the element at the start of an allocated block, due to the whole `rebind` thing going on.

Answer (score 1):

A `vector` is just a wrapper around a contiguous block of dynamically allocated memory, in other words, an array. So, if this program would work with an array allocated with `malloc` or `new`, it should continue to work with a `vector`.

(Unless it only worked "accidentally" with an array, of course, but the `vector` is unlikely to introduce extra problems.)

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard in **23.2.4** guarantees that each element of a vector<> is stored contiguously:

> The elements of a
>   vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is a vector where T is some type
>   other than bool, then it obeys the identity **&v[n] == &v[0] + n** for all 0 <= n < v.size().

It's important to notice what it says about vector < bool > , vector < bool > is a specialized vector<> that happens to try to "optimize space allocation", in some implementations it does so by storing each boolean value in a bit which pretty much renders pointer arithmetic useless.