# How can I pass a part of a vector as a function argument?

Tags: c++, vector, containers, parameter-passing, partial

I'm using a `vector` in a C++ program and I need to pass a part of that `vector` to a function.

If it was C, I would need to do the following (with arrays):

```
int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
func(arr+2);  // Pass the part of the array {3, 4, 5}
```

Is there any other way than creating a new `vector` with the last part?

Comment: "*If it was c I need to do this (with arrays):*" That would assume that `func` knew that it took an array of 3 elements (or fewer). If it expects an array of 5, you're screwed.

Comment: It's quite possible you should be doing something else entirely. Why are you passing raw data around? What does the vector represent? I would encapsulate it and perform operations on it, instead of passing it elsewhere.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A common approach is to pass iterator ranges. This will work with all types of ranges, including those belonging to standard library containers and plain arrays:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void func(Iterator start, Iterator end) 
{
  for (Iterator it = start; it !=end; ++it)
  {
     // do something
  } 
}
```

then

```
std::vector<int> v = ...;
func(v.begin()+2, v.end());

int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
func(arr+2, arr+5);
```

**Note**: Although the function works for all kinds of ranges, not all iterator types support the increment via `operator+` used in `v.begin()+2`. For alternatives, have a look at [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) and [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).

Comment: I'd say it more broadly: the function works for all **ranges**. Containers and arrays are one way of managing ranges, but they are not the only way.

Comment: @juanchopanza don't we need to pass the array or vector in this case or else we need to make to them global so that it can accessible by function?

Answer (score 8):

**The latest (C++20) approach is to use [`std::span`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one).** Create a [`std::span`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one) that *views* a part of `std::vector` and pass it to functions. Note: the elements must be continuous in memory to use `std::span` on a container, and [`std::vector` is continuous in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/849190/4510033).

```cpp
#include <span>

std::vector<int> int_vector = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::span<int> a_span(int_vector.data() + 2, int_vector.size() - 2);
for(const int a : a_span);
for(const int& a : a_span);
function(a_span);
```

Answer (score 6):

Generically you could send iterators.

```
static const int n[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
vector <int> vec;
copy (n, n + (sizeof (n) / sizeof (n[0])), back_inserter (vec));

vector <int>::iterator itStart = vec.begin();
++itStart; // points to `2`
vector <int>::iterator itEnd = itStart;
advance (itEnd,2); // points to 4

func (itStart, itEnd);
```

This will work with more than just `vector`s.  However, since a `vector` has guaranteed contigious storage, so long as the `vector` doesn't reallocate you can send the addresses of elements:

```
func (&vec[1], &vec[3]);
```

Answer (score 4):

As of [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20), I would make use of a *range* from the [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges), because it offers a variety of range adaptors for creating different views on you vector. For your use case, I would use the range adaptor [`std::views::drop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/drop_view) as follows:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    // Ignore the first two elements and pass only {3, 4, 5} to func().
    func(arr | std::views::drop(2));

    return 0;
}
```

This way you don't have to bother with interators or pointer/iterator arithmetic.
Also, no temporary vector is created for your shortened `arr`, because the view adaptor `drop()` creates a range that doesn't contain elements. The resulting range is just a view over the original vector `arr`, but with a customized iteration behavior.

For the declaration of `func()` I would use the placeholder type `auto` for the function parameter, because the type of the resulting range is quite complex. This makes `func()` a [function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template), though:

```
void func(auto range) {
    for (int i : range)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

(Alternatively, you could pass `arr` by reference to `func()` and apply the range adaptor inside `func()`.)

Output:

> 3
> 4
> 5

[Code on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ykPAW7TfrVjeGt31)

Comment: Or ```template <T> void func(T range)```, [see more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30665596/8366223)

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<char> b(100); 
send(z,&b[0],b.size(),0);
```

Try out this.

[Read this too.](http://techlogbook.wordpress.com/2008/12/01/sendreceive-c-vector-using-mpi/)

Comment: You mean `&b[2]`, don't you?  `&b[0]` yields the wrong result.

Comment: This works great for vectors, as they are contiguous. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168/are-stdvector-elements-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous. Just be careful not to try this type of thing with a non-contiguous storage containers.

Answer (score 0):

As some others already stated you can use iterators for that. You'll have to pass the start of the sequence and the end of the sequence to your worker function.

If you need more flexibility, you should take a look at `slice`. With `slice` you can for example retrieve every n-th entry of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck to same problem.I found one really nice trick.Suppose you want to find the minimum in range `L` to `R` (both inclusive) of `arr` then you can do something like this:

```
vector<int>arr = {4,5,1,3,7};

int minVal = *min_element(begin(arr)+L,begin(arr)+(R+1));
```

Means you pass the complete array and range and then you can apply the above trick.