# 'auto' not allowed in function prototype with Clang

Tags: c++, auto, c++14, clang++

Using Clang 3.5, 3.6, or 3.7, with the flag `std=c++1y` the following code does not compile :

```
#include <iostream>
auto foo(auto bar) { return bar; }
int main() {
  std::cout << foo(5.0f) << std::endl;
}
```

The error given is :

> error: 'auto' not allowed in function prototype

I do not have errors using g++ 4.9.
Is this error produced because Clang has not yet implemented this functionnality yet or is it because I am not allowed to do that and GCC somehow permits it ?

Comment: I think you should not do that since you use it out of scope.

Comment: `auto` function parameters of ordinary (non-lambda) functions are an extension from the Concepts TS. They're not part of C++14, which is what C++1y became.

Comment: Btw, there's a(n inofficial?) [clang branch](https://github.com/faisalv/clang/tree/enhanced-auto-c%2B%2B1z) that supports it. Some discussion can be found on the [std-discussion mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-discussion/PaKP8EIIlEU/discussion). I don't know what's the current status of that branch, though.

Comment: BTW C++14 is out so you should use `-std=c++14` (and upgrade if your compiler doesn't have that switch).  The next version is tentatively called `c++1z`.

Comment: gcc 4.9.x may be built with concepts which is probably why you are seeing it.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. Using c++1y is therefore deprecated ?

Comment: @coincoin it was never part of the standard so we wouldn't call it deprecated, but there's no sense in using it unless you are stuck with an old compiler

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As we see from the ISO C++ discussion mailing: [decltype(auto) parameters vs. perfect forwarding](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.c%2B%2B.isocpp.general/2438) auto parameters of non-lambdas is part of [concepts lite](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3889.pdf) and therefore not in C++14:

> clang is correct in the sense that we don't yet have auto parameters.
>   Concepts lite may bring those, but C++14 doesn't have them.

If we use the [-pedantic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) flag with `gcc` we receive the following warning:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids use of 'auto' in parameter declaration [-Wpedantic]
  auto foo(auto bar) { return bar; }
           ^
```

So this looks like an extension.

As dyp pointed out, [polymorphic lambdas](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/04/n3649-generic-polymorphic-lambda-expressions-r3) did make it into C++14 and do allow auto parameters, an example taken from the paper:

```
// 'Identity' is a lambda that accepts an argument of any type and
// returns the value of its parameter.
auto Identity = [](auto a) { return a; };
int three = Identity(3);
char const* hello = Identity("hello");
```

Which is incidentally the same functionality you want to implement in your example.

Comment: @coincoin I added a link to the gcc documentation, `-pedantic` forces the compiler to issue warnings for extensions, basically anything not allowed by the standard.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I think they not make it standard due to function overloading issue? mean with the auto keyword function overloading can be ambiguous?

Comment: @UnKnown as I said it is part of the concepts-lite proposal and so will come in with those changes.

Comment: The first link is _now_ broken ?

Answer (score 11):

Although your specific syntax did not make it to C++14, a similar option which did is:

```
static auto foo = [](auto bar) { return bar; };
```

which achieves basically the same thing.

Comment: MM, Can you explain please why `static auto`?

Comment: @UnKnown this means the name `foo` has *internal linkage*, i.e. it is not accessible by name from other units.  This prevents accidental undefined behaviour if another file went `int foo = 5;` for example.  It would not make much sense to use external linkage here because you can't write a declaration for a lambda (other than the actual definition) so no other unit would be able to correctly use it anyway.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a template instead:

```
template<class A>
A foo(A bar) { return bar; }
```

Auto is only allowed when the Compiler can deduce the type from the context.

Comment: Doesn't work for extern "C" linkage, when the auto version would have

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot infer the type from the context.

What's wrong with doing

```
template<typename Y>
Y foo(Y bar){return bar;}
```

and must you pass `bar` by value?

In your case you can use the *trailing return type* syntax:

`auto foo(auto bar) -> decltype(bar)`

Comment: @Bathsheba `auto` is not permitted in the parameter list (but the return type auto without `->` is allowed in C++14)

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't the compiler infer the type when passed as a function parameter ?