# 'auto' as a template argument placeholder for a function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, auto, c++20

C++20 allows using `auto` for function parameter type.

Does it also allow using `auto` as a template argument placeholder (not similar, but in the spirit of [C++17 template<auto>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026884/advantages-of-auto-in-template-parameters-in-c17) in a way) for function parameter type?

So the following code, pre C++20:

```
template<typename First, typename Second>
void printPair(const std::pair<First, Second>& p) {
    std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second;
}
```

Could be written as:

```
void printPair(const std::pair<auto, auto>& p) {
    std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second;
}
```

It [does compile and works nicely](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f17c1cc4ea68e09e) with experimental GCC implementation for concepts.

Is it a legitimate syntax with C++20?

---

<sub>Related: [Wildcard for C++ concepts saying "accepting anything for this template argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60400537/wildcard-for-c-concepts-saying-accepting-anything-for-this-template-argument)</sub>

Comment: From what I've heard, unconstrained `auto` *directly* translates into  templatised `typename XYZ`, which would strongly imply that it is the legitimate syntax. ***Neat***.

Comment: Note that Clang [disagrees](https://godbolt.org/z/jJZAZw) and that Clang and GCC have the same disagreement about whether `auto` is allowed in `[](const std::pair<auto, auto>& p){}` (whether with `-std=c++2a` or `-std=c++17`).

Comment: Related: [Is auto in template parameter list in lambdas part of the standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322255/is-auto-in-template-parameter-list-in-lambdas-part-of-the-standard)

Comment: Thank you @DavisHerring - I've fixed the wording

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This syntax is valid in the C++ Concepts Technical Specification, but not in C++20. In C++20 concepts, `auto` is only permitted at the top level in a function parameter type. The relevant rule is [[dcl.spec.auto] paragraph 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#2):

> A *placeholder-type-specifier* of the form *type-constraint*[opt] `auto` can be used as a *decl-specifier* of the *decl-specifier-seq* of a *parameter-declaration* of a function declaration or *lambda-expression* and, if it is not the `auto` *type-specifier* introducing a *trailing-return-type* (see below), is a *generic parameter type placeholder* of the function declaration or *lambda-expression*. [Note: Having a generic parameter type placeholder signifies that the function is an abbreviated function template (9.3.3.5 [dcl.fct]) or the lambda is a generic lambda (7.5.5 [expr.prim.lambda]). —end note]

(If you check the wording in the most recent working draft at the time of writing, you will find a somewhat different rule. The above rule was modified by [core issue 2447](http://wg21.link/cwg2447), which was voted into the C++20 final draft at the Prague committee meeting a week ago.)

The *decl-specifier*s in a function parameter are the initial sequence of keywords and type names at the start of the parameter declaration. The above rule allows `auto` there at the top level:

```
void f(auto x);
```

... but only as a *decl-specifier*. `auto` is not permitted when nested within a *decl-specifier*:

```
void f(std::vector<auto> x);
```

... and is also not permitted elsewhere in the parameter type:

```
void f(void (*p)(auto));
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that! The CWG link currently gives 404, so can you briefly explain the rationale for this restriction?

Comment: Sorry, the CWG issue and its wording change isn't publicly visible yet. The rule in question was introduced by http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1141r2.html and the intent / rationale was to be consistent with what we already allowed for generic lambdas.

Comment: @L.F.: The CWG issue isn’t really relevant anyway: it corrected a wording error that implied that certain uses of `auto` for a trailing return type counted as this kind of `auto` usage.

Comment: Are functions with `auto` parameters (`void f(auto x) {}`) limited to being defined in header files just like templated functions? Is it possible to explicitly instantiate them as well in order to define them in a separate `cpp` source file?