# Is there an elegant way to declare a set of functions with the same template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

For instance, let's say I have a simple 2D vector templated structure:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vec { T x, y; };
```

And a generic way to do summation:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto operator+(const Vec<T>& u, const Vec<U>& v) {
    return Vec<decltype(u.x + v.x)>{u.x + v.x, u.y + v.y};
}
```

But I have to rewrite `template <typename T, typename U>` for all the other basic operations (-, *, / etc.). I wish I could do something like:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
{
    constexpr auto operator+(const Vec<T>& u, const Vec<U>& v) { /* ... */ };
    constexpr auto operator-(const Vec<T>& u, const Vec<U>& v) { /* ... */ };
    /* ... */
}
```

Also, as said in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358154/auto-as-a-template-argument-placeholder-for-a-function-parameter), `auto` is not permitted when nested within a decl-specifier, which means that the below solution isn't valid (even if it compiles somehow):

```
constexpr auto operator+(const Vec<auto>& u, const Vec<auto>& v) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Perhaps use macros?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but aren't macros considered as evil and a bad practice?

Comment: Should I say evil is subjective? :P What you wish to do can only be done through macros in C++, if at all.

Comment: Is it really that onerous to repeat `template <typename T, typename U>` line for each operator? C++ template metaprogramming is verbose; we all have to live with that.

Comment: 1. macros are evil. 2. your code should clearly state what it is doing and be easy to read. So, just use the full invocation for each operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can save one template parameter, by defining the operators inline:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vec {
    T x, y; 
    template<class U> auto operator+(Vec<U> const& v)
    { return Vec<decltype(x + v.x)>{x + v.x, y + v.y};}
    template<class U> auto operator-(Vec<U> const& v)
    { return Vec<decltype(x - v.x)>{x - v.x, y - v.y};}
};
```

If you completely want to avoid writing repetitive code, macros would be a way to avoid that (whether that is good practice, and whether it helps or disturbs understanding the code, is probably a question of taste and context)