# What does the C++14 standard say regarding auto as argument type

Tags: c++, c++14, auto

Lets take a look at the following code below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Test(int _x) :
        x(_x)
    {
        std::cout << "Im being constructed" << std::endl;
    }

    int getx()
    {
        return this->x;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Test& other)
    {
        os << other.getx();
        return os;
    }
};

auto func(auto x)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return x.getx();
}

int main()
{
    auto y = func(20);

    return 0;
}
```

How does the compiler decide if (20) should be an int or Test object? The constructor for Test is not explicit so what does the standard say about it?

Comment: 1. `auto` as a parameter is part of concepts ts. 2. `x` is deduced to `int`, not `Test`

Comment: [gcc accepts auto parameters even though it is part of concepts-lite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665506/auto-not-allowed-in-function-prototype-with-clang/30665723#30665723) although if you use `-pedantic` gcc will warn this is not iso C++.

Comment: Ok thank you, so the standard allows the use of auto for lambdas but not functions, am I correct?

Comment: yes, it's allowed for generic lambdas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So although gcc allows auto as a parameter in functions this is not part of C++14 but part of [concepts-lite](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3889.pdf) which [may become part of C++1z](http://herbsutter.com/) according to Herb Sutter's last trip report.

I believe gcc allows this as an extension and if we compile your program using `-pedantic` gcc will warn:

```
 warning: ISO C++ forbids use of 'auto' in parameter declaration [-Wpedantic]
 auto func(auto x)
           ^
```

So from concept-lite proposal we can see that:

```
auto func(auto x)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return x.getx();
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
template <typename T1>
auto func(T1 x)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return x.getx();
}
```

and therefore `x` will be deduced as *int*. The compiler will rightfully give you an error like the following one from gcc (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mYMlXpUNbX52GKRY)*):

```
error: request for member 'getx' in 'x', which is of non-class type 'int'
     return x.getx();
                   ^
```

This is covered in the proposal section `5.1.1` *[dcl.fct]*:

> The use of auto or a concept-name in the parameter-declaration-clause
>   shall be interpreted as the use of a type-parameter having the same
>   constraints and the named concept. [ Note: The exact mechanism for
>   achieving this is unspecified. —end note ] [ Example: The generic
>   function declared below
>
> ```
> auto f(auto x, const Regular& y);
> ```
>
> Is equivalent to the following declaration
>
> ```
> template<typename T1, Regular T2>
>   auto f(T1 x, const T2&);
> ```
>
> —end example ]

Comment: Cheers mate, you and Piotr Skotnicki provided me with good answers.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for `auto` as argument type are the same as for template arguments.

`auto func(auto x)` is equivalent to `template<typename T> auto func(T x)`

I am no lawyer to quote the standard on the specific rules, though.

Comment: You should add that this is only true after C++1z w/ concepts lite.