# Declaring function parameter type as auto

Tags: c++, gcc, auto

I am using GCC 6.3 and to my surprise the following code fragment did compile.

```
auto foo(auto x) { return 2.0 * x; }
...
foo(5);
```

AFAIK it is GCC extension. Compare to the following:

```
template <typename T, typename R>
R foo(T x) { return 2.0 * x; }
```

Besides return type deduction are the above declaration equivalent?

Comment: see ['auto' not allowed in function prototype with Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30665506/1708801)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Using the same GCC (6.3) with the `-Wpedantic` flag](https://godbolt.org/z/sG3xjv) will generate the following warning:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids use of 'auto' in parameter declaration [-Wpedantic]
  auto foo(auto x)
          ^~~~
```

[While compiling this in newer versions of GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/eXdJwX), even without `-Wpedantic`, will generate this warning, reminding you about the `-fconcepts` flag:

```
warning: use of 'auto' in parameter declaration only available with -fconcepts
  auto foo(auto x)
          ^~~~
Compiler returned: 0
```

And indeed, [*concepts*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) make this:

```
void foo(auto x)
{
    auto y = 2.0*x;
}
```

equivalent to this:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T x)
{
    auto y = 2.0*x;
}
```

[See here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Parameter_list): "If any of the function parameters uses a placeholder (either `auto` or a constrained type), the function declaration is instead an ***abbreviated function template declaration***: [...] (concepts TS)" -- emphasis mine.

Comment: This is now a standard feature of C++, since it was [added in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60355539/975097).