# Pass subarray to function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function to which I need to pass an array.

But I don't want to pass the entire array (e.g., valid indices from array[0] to array[size-1]), but a subarray (e.g., valid indices starting at array[5] to array[size-1]).

Is there a way to do that in C++?

Comment: 1. Classic C++ array hasn't conception of 'subarray'. 2. Cost remain the same, array is passed by pointer, You can pass array and two indexes.

Comment: Or you can use iterator concept by passing pointer to the first element and pointer after the last element.

Comment: You cannot pass an array to a function. When you try to, you actually pass the address of the first element of the array. If you need a subarray that starts at 5, you just pass the address of the fifth elements. You shouldn't be using C-style arrays anyway. Use std::vector and iterators, this is the C++ way.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer array to function parameter below

```
void Foo(int* arr, int length);
//call Foo
Foo(&a[0], length); //or
Foo(a, length);
```

you can also transfer a certain range of array.

```
Foo(&a[1], length);
Foo(a + 1, length);
```

Just, simple code.

```
#include <iostream>
void Print(int* arr, int length)
{
    for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        std::cout << *(arr + i) << ", ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    //type A
    Print(&a[0], sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)); //print all element of a
    Print(&a[1], 3); //print 2,3,4

    //type B
    Print(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)); //print all element of a
    Print(a + 1, 3); //print 2,3,4

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Quoted comment by n.m.:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445240/pass-subarray-to-function/39446176#comment66214997_39445240)

> You cannot pass an array to a function. When you try to, you actually pass the address of the first element of the array. If you need a subarray that starts at 5, you just pass the address of the fifth elements. You shouldn't be using C-style arrays anyway. Use std::vector and iterators, this is the C++ way.

As indicated, you can add an offset to the array base pointer (and subtract from the passed arraysize accordingly).

Or pass `begin` and `end` (one past the end) pointers of the array to the function to achieve an "iterator-style" implementation.

[But as you are programming C++, please consider to use `std::vector`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16983343/1025391)

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int arr[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
}

void bar(int* begin, int* end) {
    while (begin != end)
        std::cout << *begin++ << ' ';
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);

    // pass entire array
    foo(arr, size);
    //bar(arr, arr+size);
    std::cout << '\n';

    // pass array starting at index 5
    foo(arr+5, size-5);
    //bar(arr+5, arr+size);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The output is:

```
$ g++ test.cc && ./a.out
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
5 6 7 8 9
```