# read binary file into the address of vector element

Tags: c++, vector

I have a binary file which contains doubles of size of 8 bytes. I want to read the doubles into a `vector<double>`, see below

```
  ifstream infile("x.dat", ios::binary);
  vector<double>data(filesize/8, 0.0);
  for(int i=0; i< (filesize/8); ++i)
  {
    infile.read( (char *) (&data[i]), sizeof(double) );
  }
```

I know this would work if data was a `C` array, but not sure if this will work for `vector`, since `vector` contains more stuff than a `C` array(`vector` has methods), does the address `&data[i]` mean the address of the data member of the ith element?

Comment: Yes - the code's fine (apart from not checking `infile` for open/read errors).  Why don't you run it, prove to yourself it works, and get on with the rest of the program?

Comment: `vector` is a sequential container hold data like `C` array with extra information like `size` and `capacity`. Yes it was also designed to be used as primitive arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are std::vector Elements Guaranteed To Be Continuous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168/are-stdvector-elements-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, each vector element is just a `double` object, and `&data[i]` points to that object.

In fact, all the `double` objects are in a contiguous array, so you can read them all at once:

```
infile.read((char*)data.data(), filesize);
```

Of course, as noted below, this requires the file to have been written in a format compatible with your program's binary representation of `double` values, otherwise the values will be garbage.

Comment: thanks, what does `data.data()` mean here? Does it return the address for the entire contiguous array of `double`s?

Comment: @Allanqunzi: Yes, it's the address of the first element of the array. It's the same as `&data[0]`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The OP idea is in general not portable though, since the representation of doubles can vary across different OS (when dumped into files), isn't this so?

Comment: @vsoftco: It's as portable as the posted code. If the file was written out by a program using the same representation, then it's fine. It it used a different representation, then you'll get garbage.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, how about the iterators? if `vector<double>::iterator it=data.begin()`, is `it==&data[0]` true?

Comment: @Allanqunzi: No, you can't compare an iterator with a pointer. But the address of the object it refers to, `&*it`, will be the same as `&data[0]`, since both are the address of the same object.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, yes, you are right, I just tested it. `it==&data[0]` doesn't compile. `&*it==&data[0]` works as what you said. This behavior is kind of counter intuitive. `it` and `&data[0]` are different things, but they point to the same address.

Comment: @Allanqunzi: It rather depends on your intuition. An iterator isn't a pointer (it just behaves like one in some ways), and in general you can't compare unrelated types; from that point of view, it's to be expected that you can't compare them.