# STL vector erase via pointer

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I [understand (at least I think I do)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446294/48461) that pointers can be used as random STL iterators.

Why does the following code not compile unless I cast the pointer to an iterator?

```
vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
v.erase(&v[0]);
```

Comment: Why do you think a pointer to the element is the same as a iterator (`std::vector<int>::iterator`)?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: While iterators could be implemented using pointers, a pointer is not automatically an iterator.

Comment: A pointer is an iterator, but it is not necessarily the iterator of a `vector`, which is `std::vector<...>::iterator`.

Comment: In case you don't know, you can simply say `v.erase(v.begin() + 0);`

Comment: Maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654108/c-stdvectoriterator-is-not-a-pointer-why

Comment: There has been implementations where this would work, `VC6` might have been one. The `iterator` type *is allowed* to be a pointer, but can also be a class. And then your code doesn't work.

Comment: @ishpreet It is the other way around.

Answer (score 12):

You can pass pointers to *algorithms* like `std::sort`, `std::find`, or `std::copy`. These are templates that are configurable for anything that works as an appropriate iterator.

This does not mean that different iterators necessarily convert to each other.

The method `erase` of the `std::vector<int>` container can only work with iterators to elements of the same vector. As has been pointed out this may be implemented as a pointer, but it usually is not, for reasons stated here:
[C++ std::vector<>::iterator is not a pointer, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32654108)

Consider `std::find`:

```
template< class InputIt, class T >
InputIt find( InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value );
```

Here `InputIt` is a template parameter. The template `std::find` will work with any iterator type that fulfills the requirements of an [input iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), and whose `operator*` returns something that can be compared to type `T`. Pointers work well here. As Fire Lancer pointed out correctly in a comment, both `first` and `last` must be of type `InputIt`.

Now compare this to [std::vector::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

```
iterator erase( const_iterator pos );
```

This takes a `const_iterator`, which is one of the typedefs of the `std::vector` class. This is one particular type of iterator, not a template parameter.

Comment: Well passing **pairs** of pointers to those algorithms is effectively a random access iterator type. But, you still cant pass a pointer and a vector iterator as a "pair" to those, even if the pointer is inside the vector.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `vector.erase(...)` is

`iterator erase( const_iterator pos );`

The `const iterator` is a class in itself.
So if there was a conversion of a plain pointer to this class, then this could be done. But I don't think there is any.

But one thing is to use it in a place where an iterator is expected, and another is to use in algorithms.

Where an `iterator` is required, only a iterator can be used.

In algorithms, an `iterator` is not expected. Only a object for which a [Concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) of an [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Concepts) is satisified (usually a `begin` and `end` return the required iterator/pointer).

Comment: Algorithms expect iterators, not "objects for which a begin/end..." whatever.

Comment: Algorithms use templates - the parameters are not concrete types of ```iterator```. You can pass any object which satisfies the Concept of an ```iterator``` into the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Although pointers are iterators, they are not the same *type* as *vector* iterators (at least they do not have to be).

You can convert a pointer to an element of a vector into an itertor using iterator and pointer arithmetic like this.

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};

int* p = &v[0]; // a pointer

auto v_iter = v.begin() + std::distance(v.data(), p); // an equivalent vector::iterator

v.erase(v_iter);
```

This only works with contiguous containers like `std::vector` or `std::array`.