# why can not p = itv?(vector problem from c++)

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

This is my code:

```
vector<int>::iterator itv = vec.begin();
int *p;
p = itv; // ERROR!
```

I have a simple question:
Why `p` can not get the value of `itv`, since `p` is an address and `itv` is also an address.

thanks. ：D

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654108/c-stdvectoriterator-is-not-a-pointer-why

Comment: For what it's worth, you can obtain the address of the referred-to element using `&*itv` so long as `itv` points to a valid element

Comment: Well, an iterator is not a pointer, so they are incompatibel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general an iterator is not defined as a raw pointer.

In old versions of some compilers the iterator of the class template `std::vector` was indeed defined as just a pointer.

But in modern compilers iterators of standard containers are usually defined as objects of some classes.

You could rewrite your code snippet the following way

```
vector<int>::iterator itv = vec.begin();
int *p;
p = &( *itv );
```

But a more simple and safer way is to write

```
int *p = vec.data();
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    
    for ( int *p = vec.data(); p != vec.data() + vec.size(); ++p )
    {
        std::cout << *p << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `vector<int>::iterator` and `int*` are different types and C++ compiler does not know how to convert one to another, even though they are semantically similar. Also, [Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) is not necessarily the address in the memory (although it can be implemented as such).

Anyway, it is quite desired behavior. Imagine similar situation with

```
std::list<int>::iterator itv;
```

In this situation if you do the trick suggested in the comments `&*itv`, accessing the value under `p++` will have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to all the previous answers that, despite the fact that raw pointers are not iterators by type, they fulfill all the random-access iterator requirements and can be used in STL algorithms.

For example:

```
int arr[N];
int *begin = arr;
int *end = begin + N;

// find
int *result = std::find(begin, end, value);
if (result != end) {
  // process found
}

// or sort
std::sort(begin, end);
```