# Is there a way to check for this memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a very basic function `bool read_binary( string filename, double*& buf, int &N)` which reads data from a binary file. I call it as:

```
int N;
double* A = NULL;
read_binfile(inputfile, A, N);
delete[] A;
```

where `read_binfile` is

```
bool read_binfile( string fname, double*& buf, int &N ) { 
    ifstream finp(fname.c_str(), ifstream::binary);

    finp.seekg(0, finp.end);
    N = finp.tellg()/8;
    buf = new double[N];
    finp.seekg(0, finp.beg);
    printf("N = %i\n", N); 
    finp.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), sizeof(buf[0])*N);

    if( finp ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I find that if I (naively) loop *only* `read_binfile` then this causes a memory leak, whereas if I include `double* A = NULL` and `delete[] A` in the loop, then this leak does not occur. Is there any way (inside of `read_binfile`) to check on this type of error or does this necessitate a correct use of `read_binfile` where a `delete[]` must follow without being called again?

Comment: Use a `std::vector` and then you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: `vector` does not assure that the memory is contiguous and I need to leverage locality in the algorithm.

Comment: Yes it does. http://stackoverflow.com/a/849190/2101267

Comment: @Laurbert515 vector has been gauranteed since at least c++11 to be contiguous

Comment: @NathanOliver: Since C++03 actually, if I'm understanding the above link properly

Comment: @DarkFalcon I didn't have that one available but I had C++11.

Comment: @Laurbert515, avoid use of hard coded size 8. Replace `N = finp.tellg()/8;` by `N = finp.tellg()/sizeof(double);`.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Just got a C++03 standard.  It is guaranteed in C++03 as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver, vector was guaranteed to be contiguous since it's inception. Even in 98. That was it's basic feature, without that, it would not be a replacement for C array.

Comment: Are multi-dimensioned `vectors` given the same guarantee? I just went back to some old sites and found that only a 1-D vector has this guarantee - is this correct? Perhaps that is what I was thinking and was the source of my confusion here.

Comment: @SergeyA But it was never explicitly stated until C++03.

Comment: @Laurbert515, every vector allocates contiguos space,but two independent vectors are not contiguos to each other. Hint - vector elements of vector are independent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `std::vector<double>` for `buf`. That will automate memory management. Then, you won't need to pass `N` as an argument either. You can get the size of the buffer from the `vector`.

```
bool read_binfile(std::string const& fname,
                  std::vector<double>& buf)
{
   std::ifstream finp(fname.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary);

   finp.seekg(0, finp.end);
   size_t N = finp.tellg()/sizeof(buf[0]);
   buf.resize(N);

   finp.seekg(0, finp.beg);
   finp.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf.data()), sizeof(buf[0])*N);

   if( finp ) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

And use it as:

```
std::vector<double> A;
read_binfile(inputfile, A);
size_t N = A.size(); // Only if needed.
```