# Boost.MPI recv into slice of existing vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector, mpi, boost-mpi

```
vector<int> master(100);
vector<reference_wrapper<int>> sub = master(&master[10], &master[20]);
boost::mpi::irecv(source, tag, sub);
```

Is the above valid and functional to recv and update a subset of the vector?

If not, is there an equivalent alternative other than recv and copy?

Comment: Please note I have fixed the excessive `<<` in your post. Also take a look at the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thanks @Zulan. I posted the question from cell phone, The best I could do was use redundant <<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is **not valid**, as your compiler will happily tell you. There is no such constructor for a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>`. Also `reference_wrapper` does not magically work this way.

One might think, that `boost::iterator_range` would be a good idea to use in this case, but it does not support serialization. So aside from building you own range adapter that supports serialization, you have to do it manually. This is fortunately very simple by using the array overload:

```
comm.irecv(source, tag, &master[10], 10);
```

This works because `std::vector` is [guaranteed to use contiguous storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/849190/620382). Note, you **must also send the data in the array form**. Do not just send a smaller 10-element vector.