# Is std::vector::begin() from priorC++11 equivalent to std::vector::data() in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Is `std::vector::begin()` from prior-`C++11` equivalent to `std::vector::data()` in C++11?
The reason I'm asking this, earlier than C++11, I used to treat std::vector::begin() as a pointer but after C++11, it's not, and i cannot cast to a pointer equivalent. So, can I use data() instead after C++11?

Comment: std::vector::begin() was never a pointer.

Comment: If you used to treat `std::vector::begin()` as a pointer, you were relying on a particular implementation's representation of `std::vector::iterator`s as pointers. It was never guaranteed to be that way.

Comment: Are you using `&(*std::vector::begin())` to get a pointer to the vector data?

Comment: Is the documentation confusing, so that you have to ask? If it is, what exactly is confusing there?

Comment: it is just as a curiosity, but std::basic_string had data method in c++03 standard as well (const version). const CharT* data() const;

Answer (score 8):

No, `begin` returns an iterator, whereas `data` returns a pointer. For a given implementation, these may be the same thing, but you shouldn't count on this.

Comment: In addition to this, the memory of `std::vector` was not guaranteed to be contiguous before C++11 -- though in practice an implementation that does otherwise would perhaps be a bit silly.

Comment: @alcedine Actually that was rectified in C++03.  It was only C++98 and before that did not guarantee it.

Comment: @alcedine, not true. Was contiguos from at least 2003, and I have a pretty strong feeling it was contiguos in 98.

Comment: Very few implementations actually have iterators as pointers nowadays.

Comment: @alcedine: You're thinking of `std::string`.  `std::vector` has always been contiguous, because it's always been designed as a wrapper around a buffer usable for C interop.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was not able to find any normative requirements in 98 standard for vector to be contiguos...

Comment: @SergeyA: I can't find an explicit statement either.  On the other hand, there are some requirements around pointer invalidation which might be hard to meet with non-contiguous storage.  As a whole, the entire thing is badly underspecified though.

Comment: I stand corrected in that it was C++98, but I believe I do have the correct container: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168

Comment: Yeah C++ 98 doesn't come out and say it but making a non-contiguous vector that satisfies all of the vector requirements is just silly as it would be overly complex and maybe not possible.  For all intents and purposes it is fine.  If you have an implementation where it not I would suggest just getting a new implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Using iterator as pointer is completely wrong, because of it is implementation-defined. If you still need pointer to data at iterator you should use address of dereferenced iterator, like this:

```
std::vector<int> v; v.push_back(42);
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
int * p = &*it;
```

And of course, in c++11 you can use `.data()` as pointer to vector elements.

Answer (score 2):

> Is std::vector::begin() from prior-C++11 equivalent to std::vector::data() in C++11?

Depends what you mean by equivalent. Dereferencing either will yield a reference to the first item in the vector, but the iterator returned by begin() is not guaranteed to be convertible to the pointer type returned by data().

> The reason I'm asking this, earlier than C++11, I used to treat std::vector::begin() as a pointer but after C++11, it's not, and i cannot cast to a pointer equivalent.

Your code worked through good (or bad) luck, depending on how you look at it.

> So, can I use data() instead after C++11?

There are two iterator pairs that straddle the vector's data:

`begin()` to `end()`

and

`data()` to `data() + size()`

you can use either in any standard algorithm and the result will be the same.

As a matter of good style you ought to use `begin()` to `end()` where you can (which will be almost always).