# Assigning c-array to c++ vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have a question about lifetime of onstack created arrays and about transforming them to c++ vectors. For ex I have two functions:

```
void getVector()
{ 
    auto myVector = createVectorFromArray();
}

vector<float> createVectorFromArray()
{
    float myArr[10];
    readDataFromSomewhere(myArr, 10); //some read data function with signature void(float*, size_t)
    vector<float> resVector;
    resVector.assign(myArr, myArr+10);
    return resVector;
}
```

As I understand array **myArr** will be killed as soon as we leave function **createVectorFromArray**. So iterators of vector **myVector** in function **getVector** will point to nowhere. Am I right or this works in another way? And how should I better make vector from array to return it from function in this situation?

Thank you!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign

Comment: You can't invalidate elements of a `std::vector` that simply, unless they are pointers.

Comment: Have you had problems doing this? It seems really easy to just compile it and test it out.

Comment: @LogicStuff thank you! as the saying goes, rtfm.....

Comment: @sokkyoku, yep, you're right. I should check it before asking such a simple q(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is designed to discuss the various approaches, explain them, and put them into context.

#### option 1: the native to vector copy:

```
vector<float> createVectorFromArray()
{
    // data copied once
    float myArr[10];
    readDataFromSomewhere(myArr, 10);

    // vectors are lightweight handles. zero-cost construction
    // since the optimiser will see that the next statement assigns to
    // the vector
    vector<float> resVector;

    //
    // data copied twice
    //
    resVector.assign(myArr, myArr+10);

    //
    // it's almost guaranteed that RVO will elide this copy. As of c++17
    // it's a guarantee. Returning the vector is fine
    return resVector;
}
```

Problems:

1. data copied twice
2. vector will require memory allocation

#### option 2: use the vector directly

```
vector<float> createVectorFromArray()
{
    // Will allocate space and
    // default-initialise the floats (i.e. they won't be initialised)
    vector<float> resVector(10);

    //
    // one data copy. perfectly safe and idiomatic.
    // std::addressof expressed intent clearly.
    //

    readDataFromSomewhere(std::addressof(resVector[0]), resVector.size());

    //
    // it's almost guaranteed that RVO will elide this copy. As of c++17
    // it's a guarantee. Returning the vector is efficient.
    return resVector;
}
```

Problems:

1. vector will require memory allocation

Better...

#### option 3 : re-use an existing vector

```
void createVectorFromArray(vector<float>& resVector)
{
    //
    // if resVector has been used before and has a capacity() of 10
    // or more, no memory allocation necessary
    //
    resVector.resize(10);

    // one copy of data
    readDataFromSomewhere(std::addressof(resVector[0]), resVector.size());
}
```

Problems:

1. perhaps not quite to easy to use the reference interface.

> How would I choose between option 2 and 3?

Option 2 is more readable (IMHO) but would be expensive if used in a loop. So for a one-off, I'd go for that.

If I'm reading data into a buffer in a loop, I'd probably want to avoid un-necessary memory allocations. So re-using the vector's capacity would be a wise move.

e.g.

```
std::vector<float> buf;
while (thereIsMoreData())
{
    createVectorFromArray(buf);   // option 3
    useTheData(buf);
    // data no longer needed, so we can re-use the vector
}
```

the alternative:

```
while (thereIsMoreData())
{
    // the passing of the vector is efficient, particularly as of c++11
    // however, we still suffer one memory allocation per loop.
    // probably undesirable in a high performance environment.
    useTheData(createVectorFromArray());   // option 2
}
```

Finally...

#### option 4:

Provide both. Allow the user the performant approach or the 'readable' approach as he/she wishes

```
void createVectorFromArray(vector<float>& resVector)
{
    //
    // if resVector has been used before and has a capacity() of 10
    // or more, no memory allocation necessary
    //
    resVector.resize(10);

    // one copy of data
    readDataFromSomewhere(std::addressof(resVector[0]), resVector.size());
}

// overload
std::vector<float> createVectorFromArray()
{
    std::vector<float> result;
    createVectorFromArray(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some use case, specially for 2 last options ? Where it better to use one rather than other ?

Comment: @Garf365 sure. basically in loops. You don't want to have to reallocate buffers all the time

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite `createVectorFromArray` like that and you don't have anymore trouble with assigning an array to vector:

```
vector<float> createVectorFromArray()
{
    vector<float> resVector(10);

    readDataFromSomewhere(&resVector[0], resVector.size());

    return resVector;
}
```

`std::vector` is contiguous memory container, so you can use it as interface with plain old C functions

Comment: This will add a massive overhead, as the vector is first filled with the data and then is copied again for the return... (comments came at the same time, im no downvoter, just a critic)

Comment: @Nidhoegger hardly a massive overhead for 10 floats. if it's a concern, just change the initialiser to resVector(10). Then the floats won't be initialised.

Comment: Yes, for 10 floats. But whats about 100? or 10000? Its unneccessary to write a function for that... And im not talking about the floats. I am talking about the vector object that copies the floats...

Comment: @Nidhoegger in the current implementation, the floats will be uninitialised. This answer is correct and idiomatic. You're wrong to downvote it.

Comment: Have not downvoted, but ideally `vectors` are not meant to be accessed (`&resVector[0]`) in that way. It breaks the framework of abstraction.

Comment: @RichardHodges: I am just stating that this is a suboptimal approach! Nothing more, nothing less!

Comment: @Nidhoegger you're wrong to say that. It's absolutely optimal.

Comment: @sameerkn not agree with you, we find this kind of implementation in "Effective stl" from Scott Meyers

Comment: IMHO its not. Also sameerkn is right. Its not the way to access vectors

Comment: @sameerkn `&vector[0]` does not break encapsulation. A vector's elements are guaranteed by the standard to be contiguous. This use case is idiomatic.

Comment: How to return efficiently the vector ?

Comment: @Garf365 the vector is returned efficiently by RVO. There is no overhead.

Comment: @Garf365: It would be "more efficient" to pass a reference of the vector from the point where you call the function rather then creating and copying the vector.

Comment: @RichardHodges, I would not advice users to rely on compiler optimization. Its a nice feature, but its wrong to rely on it... (also IMHO)

Comment: @RichardHodges: I was talking about abstraction.

Comment: @Nidhoegger But returning a local variable by reference isn't a good practice. Also, OP doesn't have use c++11 flag, so we can't use move semantic

Comment: @Nidhoegger RVO is ubiquitous. As of c++17 it is mandated by the standard. You can rely on it.

Comment: @Garf365 RVO happens prior to c++11

Comment: @sameerkn abstraction of vector allows this kind of use, accordign it's own definiton

Comment: @Garf365, this is not what I told you. Pass a reference from outside to that function and manipulate it like: `void createVectorFromArray(vector<float> &res)`

Comment: @RichardHodges: as long as you have the right optimization level. And there are not many users out there that use c++17 yet (e.g. which stable linux distributions have a recent GCC suite?)

Comment: @Garf365: OP didsn't use C++03 flag neither, so why assuming old standard over the current one ?

Comment: @Nidhoegger right for prototype, I add this solution to my answer.

Comment: @Garf365: Container `vector` only tell that its a random access and sequential data structure. Whether it stores data in continuous manner is implementation/encapsulation. `vector` provides `operator[]` for indexed/random/sequential data access and this is how it should be accessed via `[]` i.e abstraction.

Comment: @Jarod42: Because its more likely he didnt add a flag to define the standard. So assume the default one.

Comment: @sameerkn totally wrong, vector stores always data in continuous memory, it's the definition of vector abstraction. Standard says that (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168/are-stdvector-elements-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous)

Comment: And what should I do? Previous post answers my question I think, but someone downwoted it. In this post Garf365 shown another approach which also good I think.  Why someone downvote previous answer? And what is the better way, an why?

Comment: @DanielVlasenko better way is mine (of course :p)... joking aside, mine will save you a temporary useless array, less copy from one to another container.

Comment: The second approach should be used only in a heavy-duty loop, where the first one would cause performance downgrade due to allocations/deallocations. `std::getline` is an example.

Comment: @Nidhoegger: *"default"* is not the same depending of OS/compiler/version. I personally assume last standard unless specified.

Comment: @Jarod42, then I make a bet that your assumtions are more often wrong than right

Comment: @Garf365: Your example will also generate a useless copy in some cases. E.g. when optimization is turned off or you use a compiler without RVO.