# Writing contents of vector to file as binary data

Tags: c++, vector

I have some 15-year-old C++ code that I am trying to bring up to more modern times. At this stage, I'm trying to get code that compiled with Visual C++ 6.0 to now compile with VS 2003 (Microsoft Visual C++ .NET 69462-335-0000007-18915).

```
std::vector<myClassType> myVect;
...

// Assuming vector.begin() simply points to start of a contiguous array
bool OK = File.write((char*) myVect.begin(),
                     myVect.size() * sizeof(myClassType));
```

When I read the comment, I get concerned...  Can we really assume that a vector is in contiguous memory?  If not, what is a better way to do this?  Do I need to loop through the vector contents & write each set of data from myClassType?

As it is, the compiler complains about casting the result of begin() to char* anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168/are-stdvector-elements-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous

Comment: We can assume `myClassType` [is POD](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector` is guaranteed to store its elements in contiguous memory, so what you are attempting to do is OK, provided that `myClassType` is a [POD type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType).  Otherwise, you will have to loop through the `std::vector` serializing each element one at a time to a flat format as needed.

However, the `std::vector::begin()` method returns an **iterator** to the first element, not a **pointer** to the element data.  An iterator is *like* a pointer, but is *not* a pointer.  Container implementations are allowed to use actual pointers as iterators, but more times than not they use wrapper classes instead.  Do not rely on this behavior!  Use the iterator API the way it is intended to be used, and do not assume an iterator is an actual pointer.

To get a valid pointer to the data of the first element of your vector, you need to either:

1. use `std::vector::data()` (C++11 and later only):

   ```
   myVect.data()
   ```

   This is safe to use even if the vector is empty. `data()` may or may not return `nullptr` when `size()` is 0, but that is OK since `write()` will not try to access any memory when `size()` is 0.

   ```
   bool OK = File.write((char*) myVect.data(), myVect.size() * sizeof(myClassType));
   ```
2. use `std::vector::operator[]` to get a reference to the first element, then use `operator&` to get the element's address:

   ```
   &myVect[0]
   ```

   Note that `operator[]` does not perform bounds checking, and thus will return an undefined pointer if the specified index is >= `size()`, so make sure to check if the vector is empty before writing it:

   ```
   bool OK = myVect.empty() || File.write((char*) &myVect[0], myVect.size() * sizeof(myClassType));
   ```
3. same as #2, but using `std::vector::front()` instead:

   ```
   &myVect.front()
   ```

   Note that calling `front()` on an empty vector is undefined behavior, so make sure to check if the vector is empty:

   ```
   bool OK = myVect.empty() || File.write((char*) &myVect.front(), myVect.size() * sizeof(myClassType));
   ```
4. use `begin()` to get an iterator to the first element, then use `operator*` to dereference the iterator to get a reference to the element it points to, then you can get the element's address:

   ```
   &(*(myVect.begin()))
   ```

   Note that `begin()` returns the `end()` iterator when the vector is empty, and dereferencing the `end()` iterator is undefined behavior, so make sure to check if the vector is empty:

   ```
   bool OK = myVect.empty() || File.write((char*) &(*(myVect.begin())), myVect.size() * sizeof(myClassType));
   ```

Comment: I wanted to use #1, but VS 2003 is (apparently) not  C++11.  (They don't specify which version of the standard they support, so I just tried it.)  I tried #4 instead, and that compiles cleanly.  Thanks!

Comment: C++11 was officially released in 2011 (hence its name), so of course VS2003 doesn't implement it (predates it by almost a decade). [C++11 support started being added to VS in VS2010 onwards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).  #2, #3, and #4 will work in all C++ versions that support `std::vector`.  I would use #2 myself, as it is the cleanest and least overhead. #3 and #4 are functionally the same (as `front()` is implemented as `*begin()`), and #4 is clearly the ugliest of them all.

Answer (score 4):

Remy Lebeau's answer is correct.  To add to it, if you want to add more safety to your code you should also use [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) to make sure `myClassType` is safe to write like you want:

```
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(std::is_pod_v<myClassType>, "myClassType is potentialy unsafe to write as-is");
```

If somebody modifies `myClassType` in the future in a way that makes it unsafe to use in your `File.write()` code, this compile time check will catch it.

Comment: Great tip - I wanted to use this, but VS 2003 is (apparently) not C++11. (They don't specify which version of the standard they support, so I just tried it & <type_traits> could not be found.)

Comment: `static_assert` is only in C++11 and later, and it was [added to VS in VS2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).